# LTspice snubber simulation

Tags: analog, ltspice, snubber

I'm attempting to simulate a bi-directional snubber to limit the peak voltage when switching off, as shown in the picture below. The resistance of R2 changes from 1 mΩ to 1 MΩ when a current of 1 kA is detected to simulate the switching process. R4 is initially 10 Ω for 100 ms, then it becomes 1 mΩ to simulate a short circuit condition. The snubber is intended to limit the peak voltage between R1 and R2 to 3 kV, but in this simulation, it doesn't work as expected, and the peak voltage reaches around 3.6 kV. However, when I connect the line between C1 and C2 with the same resistance as R4 directly to the ground (as shown in the second picture), it successfully limits the voltage to the calculated 3 kV. Can somebody explain the difference between these two simulations or the fault in the first simulation? [image: simulation].[image: simulation 2]

Comment: Huh, is this like a distribution line fault (and recloser) situation then? L1 would then be line and transformer (leakage) inductance? (Motivation isn't required, but it's useful to solidify a problem.) Have you verified that L1 peak current is as intended? Is the voltage on [node between R2 and R7] as given (i.e. about 2V)? Is the result numerically stable, i.e. a changing resistance can be quite a dynamic problem for the simulator, you may need to change risetime or simulator settings (GEAR over "modified TRAP"?) to get reasonable results.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a very large step change on current between the resistors and capacitors. I would put a realistic amount of inductance and resistance between the resistors R1 and R7 and C1 and C3 and see if that solves the problem. Also another thing would be to put a small RC on V(C) to limit the voltage change on node C so it isn't near instantaneous, and put in a realistic rise time.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I've followed all your instructions, but I'm still struggling to get it to work. I might have misunderstood something, but I haven't achieved the desired results yet. I'm still having trouble understanding the difference between the first and second situations. The path to the ground seems almost identical, except for the high resistance of R2.

Comment: Put a really small resistor (like 1uΩ) in the first example between R2 and C1 and see how much current is going across it.

Comment: At ~100ms there is about 2.5kA going across it. with a small spike <1u to 60kA? at the start